# Changing color of positionmarker/caret

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

What is the name of the element of a text box control which I need to manipulate to achieve a change of the color  of the position marker in the text box?
The normal foreground attribute changes the actual texts color, but the position marker stays the same color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify the color of the caret (which assume is what you call "positionmarker") you have to set the [`CaretBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.caretbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `TextBox`.

Comment: Ahhh thank, especially for the correct term for it^^